# Faker uninitialized constant -- wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, faker

I just updated our app from rails 6.0 to 7.0.8 and it required me to update faker as well. This upgrade was from 1.7.3 to 2.0.0. When running our test suite, getting two errors that I'm unsure how to resolve:

```
/gems/ruby/3.2.0/gems/i18n-1.14.1/lib/i18n.rb:210:in `translate': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1) (ArgumentError)
```

and

```
Faker::Book.title[0..30]
/gems/ruby/3.2.0/gems/i18n-1.14.1/lib/i18n.rb:210:in `translate': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1) (ArgumentError)
```

As these were both working in 1.7.3, was unable to find any updates in the changelog that shows otherwise, unless it's a separate issue.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faker current version is 3.2.3, so 2.X is very outdated.

Your issue is ruby 3 kwargs related.

Did you also update ruby from 2.7 to 3.2?

Prior to Faker 2.10 ([Pull Request](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/pull/1876)) arguments were passed to `I18n#translate` as follows: [Source](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/v2.9.0/lib/faker.rb#L158)

```
I18n.translate(*args.push(opts))
```

This worked up until ruby 3 (deprecation warning in 2.7) when positional and keyword arguments were separated. See [Here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/) for more details.

In Faker 2.10 this was changed to

```
I18n.translate(*args,**opts)
```

So that the keyword arguments would be passed appropriately.

In summation the simplest solution would simply be to update faker to at least 2.10 (recommended 3.X)

Comment: This was the issue, thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that there is an issue with translation method in i18n gem. Instead, you can first assign the title to a variable, and then get the first 30 characters of that string. Here's how you can do it:

`title = Faker::Book.title`

`short_title = title[0..30]`

this will let the full title to translate and then it get shorted.

Comment: This still seems to throw an error: `title = Faker::Book.title
/gems/ruby/3.2.0/gems/i18n-1.14.1/lib/i18n.rb:210:in translate': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: there might be the conflict between your gem version.
try using another method for creating a book title,
title = "#{Faker::Lorem.words(number: 2).join(' ')}